# Overriding CSS Hover Colors and !Important

Tags: css

I'm working in WordPress and I have one part of the site colored and styled like normally but there is a secondary part of the site that is colored in darker styles.  I have been able to separate the two's CSS mostly with the use of classes and !important.  I am having a spot of trouble in the menu area.

In the majority of the site I have the following when hovering over the menu:

```
.header-menu li:hover, a:hover {
background-color: #b89230 !important;
color:#fff4d6;
text-decoration: none !important;
```

And on what part of the site I have:

```
.page-template-cryptofact-page-php .header-menu li:hover, a:hover {
background-color: #836F38;
}
```

As it is written above, the .page-template css is taking on the background color hover of the rest of the site.  If I !important the css of the page-template, then the rest of the site takes the coloring effect instead, regardless of its own !important style.

I've tried **removing** !important postscript from both, **swapping** either one, and **adding** it to both and I still cannot get them to act on their own.  I was hoping that designating .page-template-cryptofact-page-php would be enough, since it seems enough for all the rest of the styling.

When I open to inspect the element in source, all of either .header-menu or .page-template-etc is grayed out leaving the a:hover as the instigator on either problem.

I'm fairly new to the nuances of CSS, so if someone could explain why this is happening I would greatly appreciate it.

I would post the site but it is insecure so it would not be a good idea.  I can post screenshots or any other information you need.

Here I have placed a couple images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Can you show us your HTML? Can we have a snippet?

Comment: You really have to clean up your styles. Remove all of the importants and simplify your selectors and classes. Fixing messy code with more messy code just isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Redmond for the advice but it felt clean until I started trying to get either part of the site to separate its css.  Do you think this is the only problem that there is something else in the css elsewhere that is getting in the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a bit of an assumption here as to what your problem is, because I'm not 100% sure what you've got going on, but I believe you are mis-using the `,` in your selectors.

The comma breaks up totally distinct selectors, so if you want to style certain elements under a certain class, you would need to include that class on both sides of the comma, so you should end up with something like this:

```
.header-menu li:hover, .header-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #b89230;
    color:#fff4d6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.page-template-cryptofact-page-php .header-menu li:hover,
.page-template-cryptofact-page-php .header-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #836F38;
}
```

Removing the `!important`s is probably a good idea... they usually make things more difficult to maintain.

Comment: Ugh, you're entirely correct.  Sorry I may have been looking at it too long (since last night).  Thanks for explaining the comma use further though.  I will definitely go test that out right now.

Comment: I altered it and it indeed worked!  Thank you so much.  I didn't know too much about the comma part of css and indeed was misusing it.  I will go back through all my css to make sure it is done right.  Thanks for helping me learn more!